# A unit of seventh cyclotomic field

Tags: roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

I have troubles with the following problem about units.

> Show that $1+\zeta $,  $1+\zeta+\zeta^2$ are units in the field $\mathbb{Q[\zeta]}$, where $\zeta$ is a seventh primitive root of unit  ($\zeta^7=1$).

Is it possible to prove this by straightforward calculation with norms?

Comment: By units, do you mean units in the ring of integers?

Comment: Yes. Units of a field is rather easy to describe. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of a primitive seventh root of unity is:
$$\Phi_7(x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6 $$
hence:
$$ -1 = \color{red}{(1+\zeta)}(\zeta+\zeta^3+\zeta^5) $$
as well as:
$$ -1 = \color{red}{(1+\zeta+\zeta^2)}(\zeta+\zeta^4).$$

Comment: Did you acquire those answers by observation? They seem like observe-able answers. If you did, is there a more systematic way of doing this for larger expressions?

Comment: I just observed that $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ can be written as $(1+x)$ times something, or $(1+x+x^2)$ times something, since both $2$ and $3$ divide $6=7-1$.

Comment: @JackDaurizio: I appreciate the style of your answers. Many of them are like this one: instructive, clever and smart! +1

Answer (score 4):

Another way to approach this is to remember that an algebraic integer $z\in{\cal O}_K$ ($K$ a number field) is a unit if and only if $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(z)=\pm1$.

Consider $z=1+\zeta$ as in the question (now $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ and ${\cal O}_K=\Bbb Z(\zeta)$). If $\Phi(X)$ is the cyclotomic polynomial (as in Jack's answer) we have
$$
N_{K/\Bbb Q}(1+\zeta)=\prod_{j=1}^6(1+\zeta^j)=\prod_{j=1}^6(-1-\zeta^j)
=\Phi(-1)=1.
$$
A similar computation holds for $1+\zeta+\zeta^2$.